# Redirect 301 using.htaccess on a virtual server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, virtual-server

I really have done searched and read dozens of replies on this  old worn out subject.    My "virtual server" must be different to the ones I read about here.
I have no cPanel. I have a Linux platform  powered by Apache.   I know the "root" of the server is a "free domain"  which is never used and added domains sit on the webspace in folders.  I can use redirects and expires and a few other instruction used on .htaccess.  OK - redirects do not work - sometimes!  Expires worked once and never again - at least I cannot see on Google Pagespeed that an expiry as been applied to  a bunch of files.
I think teh redirects are blighted by AB Zero.html  not being AB_Zero.html or AB-Zero.html  ditto a similar issues with various folders.

The website originated in 2002 and I inherited the  file and folder names.
I tried adding " %20 " to the spaces - to no avail.
Thats the story, the question is - is there another way to handle redirects  that overcomes this problem?